# Deserializing an C# IntPtr pointing to unmanaged C++ byte array (byte*) without copying

Tags: c#, c++, serialization

Given `IntPtr ptr` pointing to some C++ `byte*` in unmanaged memory, I know that we can convert it to a C# `byte` array through `Marshal.Copy`, and then deserialize the data using this C# `byte[]` as follows:

```
 byte[] managedArray = new byte[size];
 Marshal.Copy(ptr, managedArray, 0, size);
 BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
 MemoryStream meStream = new MemoryStream();

 mStream.Write (managedArray, 0, managedArray.Length);
 mStream.Position = 0;

 var myObject = binFormatter.Deserialize(mStream) as YourObjectType;
```

But this requires a copy of the pointer data into the array first. Is there a way to directly translate the `IntPtr` itself to an object of our choice?

Comment: There is such thing as `Span` and you can wrap any memory with it. If the memory Stream class can work with it then you can definitely avoid extra copying.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=net-7.0